# How execute custom typed stored procedure in opened transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I have opened transaction from Entity Framework context and need to execute `sp_ComplexTypedProc` procedure which takes custom typed parameter and returns (selects) data

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ComplexTypedProc]
@param1 IDSource readonly 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
Person.Name as Name
Person.Gender as Gender
Person.BirthDate as BirthDate
...
from dbo.Persons Person
END
```

I try to execute procedure from C# code:

```
    var currentTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    .....

    var command = currentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction.Connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "sp_ComplexTypedProc";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    List<Guid> IdSource = new List<Guid>()
    { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };

    SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter();
    sqlParameter.TypeName = "IDSource"; //IDSource is my custom type
    sqlParameter.ParameterName = "@param1";
    sqlParameter.Value = IdSource;

    command.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

    command.ExecuteReader();
    .....
    currentTransaction.Commit();
```

But it throws following exception:

> ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Is there way to execute `sp_ComplexTypedProc` procedure inside opened transaction?

Answer (score 0):

With the TransactionalBehavior and ExecuteSqlCommand you can define how the command will be attached to the trasncation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.transactionalbehavior(v=vs.113).aspx
"Starting with EF6 Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() by default will wrap the command in a transaction if one was not already present. "

ExecuteNonQuery example:

```
  using (var sqlTxn = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Snapshot)) 
               { 
                   try 
                   { 
                       var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(); 
                       sqlCommand.Connection = conn; 
                       sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTxn; 
                       sqlCommand.CommandText = 
                           @"UPDATE Blogs SET Rating = 5" + 
                            " WHERE Name LIKE '%Entity Framework%'"; 
                       sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

                       using (var context =  
                         new BloggingContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)) 
                        { 
                            context.Database.UseTransaction(sqlTxn); 

                            var query =  context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Rating >= 5); 
                            foreach (var post in query) 
                            { 
                                post.Title += "[Cool Blog]"; 
                            } 
                           context.SaveChanges(); 
                        } 

                        sqlTxn.Commit(); 
                    } 
                    catch (Exception) 
                    { 
                        sqlTxn.Rollback(); 
                    } 
                }
```